# Proximity search with Lucene Android

Tags: android, regex, apache, lucene, proximity

> **Disclosure**: *I am beginner at Android, so after reading tips and all, I
>   am posting this question wisely. Forgive if I am wrong somewhere. I have seen many posts of SO and many other blogs but except theories,
>   I am not getting any particular solution for my code.*

I am doing project where my task is to have lucene working project to search data from json file.

Now, what I need to do exactly is, when user types something on searchView, user must get the listview dependent upon the entered text, with PROXIMITY search example.

What I have tried so far is,

```
Analyzer analyzer = null;
        QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser(string_searchText, analyzer);
        try {
            Query query = queryParser.parse("\"how today\"~10");

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), query.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Log.v("..query..", query.toString());

        } catch (org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Here, string_searchText is what user enters in searchView, and that text is stored in this string, so there could be 5-10 words, so now I have this logic for 2 words..

> I want to have logic for more words too, so what should I do?

or

> I should only work with 2 words proximity?

But I am getting below errors..

```
01-03 00:53:21.073: D/AbsListView(26352): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
01-03 00:53:21.073: D/AbsListView(26352): unregisterIRListener() is called 
01-03 00:53:21.103: D/AbsListView(26352): Get MotionRecognitionManager
01-03 00:53:21.133: D/AbsListView(26352): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
01-03 00:53:21.133: D/AbsListView(26352): unregisterIRListener() is called 
01-03 00:53:21.143: D/AbsListView(26352): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
01-03 00:53:21.143: D/AbsListView(26352): unregisterIRListener() is called 
01-03 00:53:21.193: D/AbsListView(26352): unregisterIRListener() is called 
01-03 00:53:21.303: D/AbsListView(26352): unregisterIRListener() is called 
01-03 00:53:21.313: D/AbsListView(26352): unregisterIRListener() is called 
01-03 00:53:22.524: D/WritingBuddyImpl(26352): getCurrentWritingBuddyView() 
01-03 00:53:22.694: D/AbsListView(26352): unregisterIRListener() is called 
01-03 00:53:24.456: D/AbsListView(26352): unregisterIRListener() is called 
01-03 00:53:24.646: D/AbsListView(26352): unregisterIRListener() is called 
01-03 00:53:25.227: D/AbsListView(26352): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
01-03 00:53:25.227: D/AbsListView(26352): unregisterIRListener() is called 
01-03 00:53:25.397: D/AndroidRuntime(26352): Shutting down VM
01-03 00:53:25.397: W/dalvikvm(26352): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e23930)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at org.apache.lucene.util.QueryBuilder.createFieldQuery(QueryBuilder.java:205)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParserBase.newFieldQuery(QueryParserBase.java:480)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParserBase.getFieldQuery(QueryParserBase.java:472)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParserBase.getFieldQuery(QueryParserBase.java:494)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParserBase.handleQuotedTerm(QueryParserBase.java:887)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.Term(QueryParser.java:452)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.Clause(QueryParser.java:247)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.Query(QueryParser.java:171)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.TopLevelQuery(QueryParser.java:160)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParserBase.parse(QueryParserBase.java:118)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at com.abc.luceneprac.FAQs$ResultAdapter.getView(FAQs.java:574)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2604)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1840)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:681)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:742)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1647)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2427)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14905)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4601)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1021)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14905)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4601)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14905)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4601)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1694)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1552)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14905)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4601)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14905)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4601)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2213)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2027)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1237)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5164)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:561)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:777)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5302)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
01-03 00:53:25.417: E/AndroidRuntime(26352):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And in my project 574th line is,

this: `Query query = queryParser.parse("\"how today\"~10");`

So, how can I achieve desired output.

> And I also want to apply that when this proximity is applied onto the
>   searched results, the listview must be updated that way.

Thanks.

***Update--***

What about this? Can I use this?

```
\b(?:word1(?:\W+\w+){1,3}?\W+word2|word2(?:\W+\w+){1,3}?\W+word1)\b
```

??

Answer (score 0):

`null` is not an acceptable value for the analyzer passed into the `QueryParser` constructor.  You must use an actual analyzer.

Also, the first argument to the `QueryParser` constructor isn't a query, it's the parser's default field name.  The query is passed in the `parse` method.

Comment: Thanks you @femtoRgon, let me try this.

Comment: I am still trying, but how can I apply proximity for more than 2 words?

Comment: \b(?:word1(?:\W+\w+){1,3}?\W+word2|word2(?:\W+\w+){1,3}?\W+word1)\b  is there any prob in this syntax? Can I use this?

Comment: Can you see the update? So, what will be the exact syntax now?

Comment: @JackSmith - Yes, that's *very* problematic. Yes are using regex features that lucene doesn't support, you are probably attempting a multi-term regex match, which isn't how lucene regex queries work at all, and why would you use something like that, when lucene proximity phrase queries makethis easy?

Comment: Alright thank you so much. Let me code with this QueryParser, which I am still not able to make it working run, but still I will try and will update you for the same.